# Indesign - Is it possible to update value in cell when I know ID of the product?

Tags: csv, adobe-indesign

I have a question, my colleague is creating product catalog in our company (in Indesign)

He is updating a version from last year, because we have not much new products  BUT all the prices (~7000) are new.

I have never worked with Indesign before, so my question is, is it somehow possible to update OLD prices to NEW prices using ID of products, and the price is always located in the cell next to ID? Please check screenshots.

[image: indesign]

This is the table with new Prices, in csv file.

[image: indesign]

THANKS for any help.

Nikol

Comment: Can't see your screenshots. The short answer is no. It is doable, but there is no easy way. Depends on you import you might be able to reimport or script the update.

Comment: Hello, sorry my fault, I updated images, please check one more time. I appreciate it. Nikol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible workaround is:

1. read CSV line by line and store current ID and current price
2. use current ID for doc.findText() method
3. the parent  of 1st found element should be an IDcell
4. odlPriceCell should be a current table's cell with index +1
5. use current price for new odlPriceCell contents

sample code:

```
var
mDoc = app.activeDocument,
mSource = File("~/Desktop/prices.csv"),
// mTarget = mDoc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem(),
cLine, cID, cPrice,
cFound, oldID_Cell, target_Cell,
separator = ",";
app.findTextPreferences = null;

mSource.open("r");
do {
cLine = mSource.readln().split(separator);
cID = cLine[0];
cPrice = cLine[1];
if (!cID.match(/^\d+-\d+/)) continue;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = cID;
cFound = mDoc.findText();
if (!cFound.length) continue;
oldID_Cell = cFound[0].texts[0].parent;
if (oldID_Cell.constructor.name !="Cell") continue;
target_Cell = oldID_Cell.parent.cells.item(oldID_Cell.index + 1);
target_Cell.texts[0].contents = cPrice;
} while (!mSource.eof);
mSource.close();
```

Notice mSource path to modify

Comment: Thank you very much @Cashmirek

Comment: Can i have one more question? Is it possible to mark with another color or rewrite value which was not updated by CSV? e.g. with "XXXX" - just to check if there are prices not updated by csv. Nikol

Comment: Easier way would be to mark modified cells since script is iterating through entire CSV file but possibly part of INDD prices only.

Comment: I suggest to create a new color (tint?) and add the line: 
targetCell.fillColor = newColor
==> before end of do...while loop
It will be easy to remove it when no needed - just delete a color